# Output every month in a year in foreach loop PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I have a mysql query that outputs holidays in a foreach loop. Eg. 2015 January 15th Steven holiday, March 12th jim holiday Febuary 20th  jon holiday 2016 January 10th jon holiday etc. How do I list all months in the year not just the months that holidays are book?

```
$monthx = array('January'=>null, 'Febuary'=>null, 'March'=>null, 'April'=>null, 'May'=>null, 
'June'=>null, 'July'=>null, 'August'=>null, 'September'=>null, 'October'=>null, 'November'=>null, 'December'=>null); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $year = $row['year'];
$month = $row['month'];
$years[$year][$month][] = $row;
//print_r($something);
}

foreach($years as $year => $months)  {
 echo '<b>Year &nbsp;'.$year. '</b><br>';
    foreach($months as $month => $items)  {
         echo '<b>Month &nbsp;'.$month. '</b><br>';
        foreach($items as $item) {
            echo $item['employee']. '&nbsp;-&nbsp;' .$item['startit'].'&nbsp;-&nbsp;'.$item['end'].'<br/>';
             }}}
```

The idea I had was to make an array with all the months in then merge this array with the one with all the data coming from mysql. I have tried this with no success. Any help would be great.

Comment: Your code looks good to me. What happends when you run it? "No success" is not a description of a problem. Please read [MCVE].

Comment: @Anders Not sure how to merge $monthx with $Month =row['month' to output January February March etc.  The code runs fine just from MySQL but not sure how to implement array_merge or array_merge_recursive I have duplicate keys eg. January, March that are in the mysql query. Because I am new at this not even sure this is the right way to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list all the months, you'll simply need to run a `foreach` loop through them all. No need for merging in this case:

```
$monthx = array('January', 'Febuary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 
  'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'); 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
  $year = $row['year'];
  $month = $row['month'];
  $years[$year][$month][] = $row;
  //print_r($something);
}

foreach($years as $year => $months)  {
  echo '<b>Year &nbsp;'.$year. '</b><br>';

  foreach ($monthx as $month) {
    echo '<b>Month &nbsp;'.$month. '</b><br>';
    if (isset($months[$month]))
    {
      foreach($months[$month] as $item) {
        echo $item['employee']. '&nbsp;-&nbsp;' .$item['startit'].'&nbsp;-&nbsp;'.$item['end'].'<br/>';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that I was looking into to deep when sometimes it stairs you in the face... So the logic is $monthx is the array then if month as a record, then for each item in that month in MySQL get the item and echo.  Just getting i right in my head Thanks again

Comment: One quick question how do i echo no record found if the month does not have a item do i had a else statement to the is isset

Comment: I have added the no record text thanks for your help